# How can I prevent tmux exiting with Ctrl-d?

Tags: shell, tmux

I use tmux on my server and recently I found to my cost that ctrl-d will exit tmux and lose all the session information, my intention was to simply end the ssh session but failed to notice I was still in tmux until too late.

I am aware that I should be careful in future when using ctrl-d but I wondered if there a way to prevent tmux for exiting when hitting ctrl-d by accident? A solution such as a prompt, confirmation or detaching would be fine.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To be precise, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> does not exit `tmux`, but rather a shell. If that shell is running in the only pane of the last window in the `tmux` session, the session ends and the `tmux` client exits.

To prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> from exiting the shell, you can set the `IGNOREEOF` shell variable, or set the `ignoreeof` shell option. Put one of the following in your `.bashrc` file:

```
IGNOREEOF=10   # Shell only exists after the 10th consecutive Ctrl-d

set -o ignoreeof  # Same as setting IGNOREEOF=10
```

Comment: That is excellent, thanks. I only needed it for tmux so I used `set-environment -g 'IGNOREEOF' 2` in `.tmux.conf` and now I need to hit Ctrl-d 3 times to exit and I am also warned each time with the message:  `Use "logout" to leave the shell.`

Comment: Setting IGNOREEOF environment variable have no effect in zsh, but "set -o ignoreeof" or "setopt ignoreeof" does.

Answer (score 17):

`IGNOREEOF` didn't work for me so I just bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to `detach` in .tmux.conf:

`bind-key -n C-d detach`

The `-n` means no prior escape sequence needed, like the tmux prefix.

Comment: A year and a half later, `IGNOREOF` didn't work for me before since I'm using zsh. `setopt ignoreeof` in `.zshrc` works. But I had to kill all tmux sessions for tmux to source `.zshrc`. Maybe I could have sourced `.zshrc` from within tmux...

Comment: I have been using this, but it has an annoying limitation: it detaches on any Ctrl+D, whether it's being sent to the shell or to something like `cat > some_new_file.txt`.

Comment: This, however, has a side effect in tmux with more panes open as it doesn’t let you close a pane with `^D`.

Comment: ***UPDATE*** For those who want only to keep the last window/pane: `bind -n C-d if-shell -b 'USHELL="$(basename "$(getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f7)")"; [ $(tmux list-windows | wc -l) -eq 1 -a $(tmux list-panes | wc -l) -eq 1 -a $(pstree $PPID | egrep "\\b$USHELL\$" | grep -o $USHELL | wc -l) -eq 1 ]' detach 'send C-d'`

Comment: @Rohmer, prezto taught me to use `exec zsh` to restart zsh within tmux when I'm playing with the .zshrc

Comment: Your solution is very smooth, just replaced the exit to complete session detach, love it! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Besides *chepner's* answer you can stop the terminal from sending EOF entirely by setting `eof` to `undef` with `stty`:

```
stty eof undef
```

Reset with:

```
stty eof '^d'
```