# How can I prevent Tmux to close the last shell?

Tags: bash, tmux

In Tmux, I frequently start fresh shells and end them when the task I needed them for is finished. Sometimes I intend to close a window but instead close the last remaining shell. This leaves me with a plain terminal emulator.

I would like to use Ctrl-D to close shells fast and easy but prevent to close the last remaining shell as strict as possible. Thus, [this closely related question](https://superuser.com/questions/479600/how-can-i-prevent-tmux-exiting-with-ctrl-d) does not fit as it only makes closing **all** shells a bit inconvenient to prevent unintended quits. I want inconvenience only for **the last remaining** shell.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [another question](https://superuser.com/q/1466769/432690) that asks for modified <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. [My answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1466808/432690) can be adjusted to your case, the result is:

```
stty eof '^T'
bind '"\C-d": "\C-x\C-t\C-x\C-d"'
bind -x '"\C-x\C-t": _exit_maybe'
_exit_maybe() { [ -n "$READLINE_LINE" ] && return
                [ "$(tmux list-windows | wc -l)" -gt 1 ] && exit
                [ "$(tmux list-panes | wc -l)" -gt 1 ]  && exit   
              }
bind '"\C-x\C-d": delete-char'
```

Please read the other answer for explanation of the main trick. Here the function is different. Its logic:

- if the line is not empty, do nothing;
- otherwise if there is another window, `exit` the shell;
- otherwise if there is another pane, `exit` the shell;
- otherwise do nothing.

The code will affect a single shell, the one you run it in, nothing more. Pasting it into your `~/.bashrc` seems the right thing to do. You will probably want to improve the solution: check if the shell is inside `tmux` before changing the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, so shells outside of `tmux` are unaffected. Like this:

```
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
   # the above code here
fi
```

Possible problems:

- You asked about "last shell". My code prevents `exit` in Bash in the last pane in the last window. This is not equivalent, although may be enough.
- Possible race condition. Imagine two panes, two shells. One is about to exit and you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in the other one. The function "sees" the pane that is about to exit and lets the other shell exit. The two shells exit semi-simultaneously.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Checking for the last pane too is what I actually wanted. I do not consider the race condition to be an actual problem at all.